# Using Seq with Sitecore PaaS

Tags: azure, paas, logging

We are running 9.3 in an app service in Azure.

We have found a number of articles stating different things about logging in SC. Some say it's log4net, others say Serilog...

Since we cannot get to the log files in an app service, I would like to use Seq from www.datalust.co to aggregate our error logs from all our environments.

I have looked at the following article but this isn't applicable to 9.3

[Use Seq for logging with log4net instead of text file](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17199/use-seq-for-logging-with-log4net-instead-of-text-file)

Any ideas of how to get this to work correctly?

Is it using serilog or log4net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our solution wound up being more complex but I hope this helps someone looking to do the same.

So, we created a Foundation project for 'Logging' that we wrapped up the log4net source files into and were able to get it working, albeit not for all app services.

[image: Pipeline]

Needed to mod the event formatter

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The core Sitecore roles (content management, content delivery, processing, reporting) use log4net. xConnect, Sitecore Identity, and other Sitecore Host-based roles use Serilog.